# Python: Importing from module that is executed

Tags: python, import

I am creating module (with submodules). Lets call it `lib`. I am trying to make it work as following:

- I am able to run it (there is `lib.__main__`). It uses `lib.utils` inside.
- When executed part of its job is to load other file/module passed by user. Currently it does it by `importlib.import_module( name )`.
- This loaded module also needs to use `lib.utils`.

I am having following choice:

- In loaded module use `import utils` instead of `import lib.utils`. I find it somehow misleading and would like to aviod this.
- Run module in any external way, even using file with only `import lib.__main__` inside.

Only other thing I have tought of was doing `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`. Not only it seems very dirty, but also makes `log.utils` module to load twice.

Is there anything that would allow me to execute `lib.__main__`, but require using `import lib.utils` in loaded module?

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? This should work as long as `lib` and the directory holding your module to import are in the python path.

Comment: ...assuming that `lib` is a package (has an `__init__.py`)

Comment: `lib` has `__init__.py` and is located in current directory. When I add it (parent of `lib`) to PYTHON_PATH or sys.path `import lib.utils` work, but loads module again (because `lib.__main__` thinks it is using `utils`, not `lib.utils`).

Comment: From the error it seems like your main is doing `import utils`, not `import lib.utils`. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I see that it should work, but I wouldnt call it nice solution.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, but one more question... now do you run it? `python lib somemodulename`?

Comment: Yes. /*need more characters*/

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)

*If the script name refers to a directory or zipfile, the script name is added to the start of sys.path and the **main**.py file in that location is executed as the **main** module.*

In your case, if you run `python lib mymodule`, `lib` is added to `sys.path` and `__main__.py` is executed. `lib` is not a package, its simply a directory in `sys.path`. `__main__.py` is not in a package and so package-relative imports don't work.

Since `lib` is in `sys.path`, its top level `.py` files can be imported directly and any subdirectories with `__init__.py` are importable packages. So, both `__main__.py` and `mymodule` could do `import utils` and get the same thing.

Now it gets confusing. Because you are sitting in `lib`'s parent directory and because there is a `lib.__init__.py`, `lib.utils` is also valid. Its only that way because of your current directory (or maybe you added the directory to PYTHONPATH or something). So, you've got two different modules as far as python is concerned because you got there on two different paths.

The solution is to delete `lib/__init__.py`. `lib` shouldn't be package. Then you have the question of what to do with the modules like `lib/utils.py`. Normally, one would create a package directory and move the scripts there so that you get namespace encapsulation. Supposing you call that directory `mypackages`, then `__main__.py` and `mymodule.py` could both `import mypackages.utils`.